# How to style an <a> tag within an <li>

Tags: html, css

Say I have some html like this..

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menu-item-1">
    <a>Cateogry 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-2">
    <a>Category 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The thing I'm trying to do is to style each "li" element area, but also I want to style the invidual a items. I can't change the classes to something generic.

I tried

```
ul#menu li.a
```

but no dice. Do i have to include the indivdual class of the li in order to do each "a", or is there a way to say, every single li, regardless of class, that has an "a" in it.. i want to style it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... I don't really know how to explain it without the risk of being rude, but you already know how to select `li` elements inside the `ul`... just do the same for the `a`:

```
ul#menu li a
```

That said, you should really use this selector:

```
#menu>li>a
```

This is because IDs must be unique, but also because this won't interfere if you decide to add nested lists later.

Comment: i always get confused on spaces or periods or adding #'s or what needs to be where...

Comment: Nothing = tag name, `#` = ID, `.` = class, space = some descendant, `>` = first-level child. That's the basics there, after which you can add things like `[attr]` for attributes and so on.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ul#menu li a
{
}
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to *select* all `<li>` tags that contain one or more child `<a>` tags.  You'll have to either add a `class` attribute to each of your `<li>` tags, or style the child `<a>` tags like so:

```
ul#menu li > a { ... }
```

Or *all* `<a>` tags below the `<li>` like:

```
ul#menu li a { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

ul#menu li.a actually define li inside menu has class "a": like

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="a">
    <a>Cateogry 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

try

```
ul#menu li a
```

It will solve your problem. However you can checkout this page to have better understanding about CSS Selector.
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-selectors.php